# Show elements of an array in an NSTableView

Tags: macos, nstableview, nstablecellview

Assuming that I have this array of strings:
`var array = ["First", "Second", "Third"]`
I want to show each of the elements of this array in an `NSTableView` cell.
I have created the function `numberOfRowsInSection` that returns the number of empty cells, but I can't figure out how to show the string elements.

Comment: Please read [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift) : Create a Table View](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html) The principle in macOS is very similar.

Comment: This is a pretty basic operation. Try to write the code yourself, then if you are having issues, post your question and we can try to help you.

Comment: All resources are for iOS development. I couldn't find the right to do it for NSTableViewCell for Mac OS. I'm just looking for the right function.

Comment: Here is a macOS tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/830-macos-nstableview-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        return array[row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but it didn't work. I'm working on NSTableView for Mac not iOS.

Comment: fixed it for you @Alex

Comment: @Len_X This should answer your question

Comment: Thank you @Len_X , when I build the app it's still showing Table View Cell though (Which is the title)